# How do I remove every attribute from every tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to strip MS Word formatting on a paste into a Telerik RadEditer. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the built in format stripper to work.

```
//performing paste
var editor = $find("radEditor1");
editor.setFocus();
var rng = editor.getSelection().getRange();
rng.execCommand("Paste", null, false);

//does nothing! (even when uncommented)
//editor.fire("FormatStripper", {value: "MSWordRemoveAll" });
```

So I figure I could leverge jQuery to string all the attributes out of the tags and that may just do exactly what I need.

```
//fixing content
var html = editor.get_html();
$("*", html).each(function(){
    var attr = $.map(this.attributes, function(item){
        return item.name;
    });
    var node = $(this);
    $.each(attr, function(i, item){
        //added a filter for crazy Error
        if(item != "dataSrc" && 
            item != "implementation" && 
            item != "dataFld" && 
            item != "dataFormatAs" &&
            item != "nofocusrect" &&
            item != "dateTime" &&
            item != "cite")
            node.removeAttr(item);
    });  
});
editor.set_html(html);
```

Now after this function completes my html variable does not have it's html updated...

Comment: Try `return item.nodeName` instead.

Comment: Do you know what line you're getting the error on?

Comment: nodeName is giving same error, line 2764 of jquery-1.7.2.js

Comment: Try `$(html).contents()` instead of `$('*', html)`.

Comment: Not sure what's the most ideal method, but you could always just grab the raw html and modify it with a regex.  Modifying RAW html in the DOM isn't always ideal...but then again going through every atribute and adjusting the DOM tree over and over in a loop may not be best either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it.

```
var html = editor.get_html();
var parent = $('<div></div>').html(html);
$(parent).find('*').each(function(){
    var attr = $.map(this.attributes, function(item){
        return item.name;
    });
    var tag = $(this);
    $.each(attr, function(i, item){
       tag.removeAttr(item);
    });
});
editor.set_html(parent.html());​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duC6Z/8/

Unfortunately I'm still having issues with my RadEditor but that is normal.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to do the trick. It uses a `safeAttrs` array to make updating the list of attributes you want to keep easier. You can pass `.removeAttr()` a space delimited list of attributes to remove, so you don't need to loop through the attribute names one-by-one.

Finally, different browsers may handle attributes differently (Chrome, for example, stores all attributes in lowercase, so 'dataFld' is stored as 'datafld'), so it's best to normalize them all with `.toLowerCase()`

```
var safeAttrs = ["datasrc","implementation","datafld","dataformatas","nofocusrect","datetime","cite"];

$('html *').each(function() {
    var attrs = $.map(this.attributes,function(attr) {
        if($.inArray(attr.nodeName.toLowerCase(),safeAttrs) < 0) {
            return attr.nodeName;
        } else { return null; }
    });
    $(this).removeAttr(attrs.join(' '));
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/KnvDT/1/). Use Chrome or Firebug to inspect the resulting elements to check that attributes have been removed.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I think I may incorporate your safeAttrs into my solution.